# Specifying only a width on an object/embed element

Tags: html, object, width, embed, quicktime

I have the following code:

```
<object width="1000" classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
     <param id="FileNameParam" runat="server" name="src" />
     <param name="controller" value="true" />
     <embed id="EmbedObj" runat="server" width="1000" autoplay="false" controller="true" scale="aspect" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" type="video/quicktime" /> 
</object>
```

As there is no `height` attribute set for this element, I was expecting the video to fill the `width`, and the `height` to be proportion to this (just like an `img` element).

But instead, the width of the element `1000px`, but the actual player (the video and the toolbar) are `100px * 150px`.

Why is this?

How can I get the video to fill the width, and the height to be proportional?

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed, that you yourself have set the width to be 1000? When i tried with no setting, it was just fine..

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question. I wish to specify a width, and the height to be a proportion of that. If I don't set a width of 1000, then how is the element supposed to know that it is supposed to be of 1000 width?